# Unique constraint on 2 fields with special logic in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 3 columns Country,PersonID, Comments.
I want to add a database constraint which will enable multiple records for a PersonID in the same country, but will block adding the same PersonId to multiple countries.
Is it possible?

Comment: Is `X` a variable here? What conditions apply if there are no `A=1` and `B=X` rows?

Comment: I suspect you can abuse an exclusion constraint for this.

Comment: Is there a specific relation between that personid and the country, or can it be any country, but as soon as one country appears, it cannot be another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add another table to the mix, this should be doable:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonCountries (
    PersonID char(7) not null,
    Country char(3) not null,
    constraint UQ_PersonCountries_Persons UNIQUE (PersonID),
    constraint UQ_PersonCountries_XRef UNIQUE (PersonID,Country)
)
```

You can then have a foreign key from your table to this table on both the `PersonID` and `Country` columns. Since `PersonID`, by itself in the above table has to be unique, you know that each person is only linked to one country. The second unique constraint is to allow the foreign key constraint to be created.

Comment: Nice idea. In my case, since I have hundreds of such tables it means to double the number of tables and add lots of data so it isn't practical but perhaps it will help others. Thanks.